# ¿Qué hago si el import de mysql.connector no me funciona?

Tags: python, mysql

He instalado el módulo mysql.connector para Python. Sin embargo, al intentar importarlo, parece como si no estuviera instalado. Ya he verificado su instalación a través de la consola y confirmado que está instalado. ¿Cómo puedo resolver este problema?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! recibis algun error?

Comment: ¿La Consola y el IDE están usando el mismo [entorno](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+virtual+environment)?